# TextView not displaying using setText

Tags: android

I am creating my first android app which displays a series of questions with true and false buttons for options and a next button to move to next question....

The problem is that although I have used the setText to set the textview for displaying questions it is not working .. the remaining buttons`enter code here` are displaying correctly...
here is a part of my code

```
mQuestionTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);
int question = mQuestionBank[mcurrentindex].getquestion();
mQuestionTextView.setText(getString(question));
```

where mQuestionBank[] is an array of a class object,whose method getQuestion(),returns a question...

can someone plz.. help me out .. have searched all the related questions but could not find my problem listed.

all the questions are in strings.xml file and I am using the above code to access it but I don't know how to use the main textview id question_text_view in strings.xml file..

the two xml files are...

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="24dp"
android:id="@+id/question_text_view" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/true_button"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/true_button" />
<Button      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/false_button"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/false_button" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/next_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">GeoQuiz</string>
<string name="next_button">Next</string>
<string name="question_oceans">The Pacific Ocean is larger than the
Atlantic Ocean.</string>
<string name="question_mideast">The Suez Canal connects the Red Sea and the  
Indian Ocean.</string>
<string name="question_africa">The source of the Nile River is in 
Egypt.</string>
<string name="question_americas">The Amazon River is the longest river in
the Americas.</string>
<string name="question_asia">Lake Baikal is the world\'s oldest and deepest 
freshwater lake.</string>
<string name="true_button">True</string>
<string name="false_button">False</string>
<string name="correct_toast">Correct!</string>
<string name="incorrect_toast">Incorrect!</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Debug your `getString(question)`. Does it really return something?

Comment: what is getString(int) doing? we need to see inside...

Comment: Probably, `getString(question)` might be returning `null`. that's why nothing shown up. else the `visibility` of the `mQuestionTextView` either `INVISIBLE` or `GONE`. else `mQuestionTextView` overlapped by another view. else `You're referring a view from another layout`. Would you please post the `xml`.

Comment: Does the question variable refer to some R.string value? If not, it will return null